# Misaligning Buttons in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, calculator

I am attemtping to put together a basic calculator to help practice some HTML and CSS. I ran into a problem quite early that I cannot seem to remedy. Some of the buttons are misaligning and I cannot figure out why.

https://jsfiddle.net/4sLn7kax/1/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Calculator # 2!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles_2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class=" calculator">
    <div class="display">
      10000000000010000
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">%</button>
      <button class="">CE</button>
      <button class="">C</button>
      <button class="">&#x2190</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class=""><sup>1/</sup>&#x1D4B3;</button>
      <button class="">&#x1D4B3;<sup>2</sup></button>
      <button class="">&#8730;</button>
      <button class="">&#247;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">7</button>
      <button class="">8</button>
      <button class="">9</button>
      <button class="">&#215;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">4</button>
      <button class="">5</button>
      <button class="">6</button>
      <button class="">&#8722;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">1</button>
      <button class="">2</button>
      <button class="">3</button>
      <button class="">&#43;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class=""><sup>&#43;/</sup>&#8722;</button>
      <button class="">0</button>
      <button class="">.</button>
      <button class="">=</button>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue, pink);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.calculator {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.row {
  height: 80px;
}

.display {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  
}
```

I made a div with class calculator as a container element to contain all of the rows, and then 6 subsequent rows therein for the buttons. All buttons have the same dimensions and padding/margin, aswell as all rows being the same, so I cannot seem to understand why this is happening. The buttons seem to be aligning correctly horizontally, but the vertical space in between is not universal, as can be seen with the square root and +/- symbol respectively. I have tweaked some of the code and messed with the height/width of the rows but cannot figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: hi, please add also your CSS

Comment: Added the CSS code just now. I noticed the buttons that were misaligning had superscript in the value. Once I removed superscript they aligned. Is there any way to do superscript within a button without that happening?

Comment: in the code snippet your provided, the buttons aling perfectly. looks neat. However I would recommend, to solve it with a CSS-Grid or flexboxes instead of an inline-buttons. Last but not least, those buttons should get an unique ID for firing the JS scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using either CSS [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Both are designed to help in creating the layout you're after. Here's an example using Flexbox:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue, pink);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.display {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 280px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class=" calculator">
  <div class="display">
    10000000000010000
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="">%</button>
    <button class="">CE</button>
    <button class="">C</button>
    <button class="">&#x2190</button>

    <button class=""><sup>1/</sup>&#x1D4B3;</button>
    <button class="">&#x1D4B3;<sup>2</sup></button>
    <button class="">&#8730;</button>
    <button class="">&#247;</button>

    <button class="">7</button>
    <button class="">8</button>
    <button class="">9</button>
    <button class="">&#215;</button>

    <button class="">4</button>
    <button class="">5</button>
    <button class="">6</button>
    <button class="">&#8722;</button>

    <button class="">1</button>
    <button class="">2</button>
    <button class="">3</button>
    <button class="">&#43;</button>

    <button class=""><sup>&#43;/</sup>&#8722;</button>
    <button class="">0</button>
    <button class="">.</button>
    <button class="">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see elements that are in a table-like layout, I always think about using grid... It is probably one of the best additions to CSS! If you want to learn more about CSS Grid I have added a few sources at the end of my answer.

So, like I said above, grid is probably how you want to go about doing this...
I just played around with your jsfiddle and came up with a solution:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue, pink);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.display {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  
}

.calculator {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.calculator .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Calculator # 2!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles_2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class=" calculator">
    <div class="display">
      10000000000010000
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">%</button>
      <button class="">CE</button>
      <button class="">C</button>
      <button class="">&#x2190</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class=""><sup>1/</sup>&#x1D4B3;</button>
      <button class="">&#x1D4B3;<sup>2</sup></button>
      <button class="">&#8730;</button>
      <button class="">&#247;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">7</button>
      <button class="">8</button>
      <button class="">9</button>
      <button class="">&#215;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">4</button>
      <button class="">5</button>
      <button class="">6</button>
      <button class="">&#8722;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class="">1</button>
      <button class="">2</button>
      <button class="">3</button>
      <button class="">&#43;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button class=""><sup>&#43;/</sup>&#8722;</button>
      <button class="">0</button>
      <button class="">.</button>
      <button class="">=</button>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The only thing that I added was two CSS blocks:

```
.calculator {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);

  /* Change this to "start" if you don't want the calculator centered horizontally */
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* This gives the space between rows */
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.calculator .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* This gives the space between columns */
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

CSS Grid sources:

- [Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/guide-css-grid)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)
- [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)